# How to protect files in upload folder being executed

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I have a upload folder where users can upload anything, all file types are allowed...

But, there is a problem...

If user upload .php file, that file won't be offered to download it, it will be executed, so if user upload dangerous php file, that will delete folders, or browse, or display secured data, it will do that, so anyone can have access to server...

How can I protect executing in that folder?

I try with CHMOD 755 for that folder, but then files can't be uploaded...

Is there any way to protect this without php scripts or file type checking while upload or something, just to block executing in that specific folder...

Maybe with .htaccess or something?

Thank you...

Comment: I used this in .htaccess, and it's working great:


<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|p[ly]|php[345]?|[sp]html?)$">
deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Hope someone will find this useful too :)

Comment: Is it possible to add index.html file in upload folder?

Comment: dont forget to add new lines to the filesmatch pattern of @SharkTheDark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in the .htaccess of the folder to disable PHP:

```
php_flag engine off
```

In case you're using FastCGI or not `mod_php`:

```
RemoveHandler .php
```

Comment: This will only work if using mod_php.  It will not work for suphp, fast-cgi, fpm, etc...

Comment: @frw, nice... However, from a security POV, it seems a bit unreliable to rely on .htaccess. :-|

Answer (score 4):

put the directory outside the public www-scope and use a script the fetches the file using file_get_contents or similar.

Comment: Like I said: **Is there any way to protect this without php scripts**... Can that be done other way?

Comment: Since php-files isn't even x:ecuted, but simply read, the only solution I can think of is adding a new virtual host with php and cgi disabled

Answer (score 3):

My first inclination is to say "Don't do that!".

But if you *must* do it for whatever reason: upload the files into a directory that's not accessible by Apache. Then write a script that reads the files and outputs their contents.

It's still a bad idea IMHO. That doesn't prevent someone from using Javascript to do all sorts of nasty things to other users.

**Edit**
Based on your comments I'm adding a bit to my answer:

You have to remember that on the web there are multiple layers of "execution", and really it's interpreted, but I won't argue semantics. If Apache serves your file and it is designed to be interpreted by Apache, Apache will interpret it (usually a scripting language such as PHP). If you download a file designed to be interpreted by the browser (HTML, Javascript, CSS), it will be interpreted by the browser and all of the programs that go along with that.

If you can't use a script to read the file (which will only prevent Apache from doing something with it) you could have your uploader ZIP the file. That way it's always being downloaded in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you filter php files? do you really need your users uploading php file? you can filter for known dangerouns extensions.